# Google api - bigquery & Appengine - cannot create dataset

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a new Dataset inside Google Bigquery while using Google App Engine as a server .

this is the code i was using -

```
set_include_path("Google/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Service.php';
require_once 'Client.php';
require_once 'Service/Resource.php';
require_once 'Model.php';
require_once 'Collection.php';
require_once 'Service/Bigquery.php';

$project_id = "test";
$dataset_id = "TestDataset";

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Bigquery::BIGQUERY);

$bigquery = new Google_Service_Bigquery($client);

$ConfigureDataset = new Google_Service_Bigquery_DatasetReference();
$ConfigureDataset->setProjectId($project_id);
$ConfigureDataset->setDatasetId($dataset_id);

$dataset = new Google_Service_Bigquery_Dataset();
$dataset->setDatasetReference($ConfigureDataset);
$dataset->setDescription($dataset_id);

$options = array();

$response = $bigquery->datasets->insert($project_id,$dataset,$options);
```

The error I am getting is -

```
  Fatal error: Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found in /base/data/home/apps/1.392457623149040913/Google/Client.php on line 963
```

On Client link 963 i found this -

```
protected function createDefaultLogger()
{
$logger = new Logger('google-api-php-client');
$logger->pushHandler(new MonologStreamHandler('php://stderr', Logger::NOTICE));

return $logger;
}
```

Than i looked for this class on the Google api and didn't find it .

This is the api i downloaded -

```
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client
```

What can be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the autoload file, rather than setting the include path. There are two ways to do this. The first, which we recommend, is to install this library via [composer](https://getcomposer.org):

1. After installing composer, run the following command in the root of your project, and then require the autoload from *your* vendor:

   ```
   $ cd /path/to/project
   $ composer require "google/apiclient:2.0.0@RC"
   ```
2. In your project, require the autoload file instead of using that `set_include_path` business:

   ```
   require_once '/path/to/project/vendor/autoload.php`;
   ```

The *other* way (which is more along the lines of what you're trying to do) is to download a package with all the dependencies, and require the autoloader for JUST our package:

1. Download the file [google-api-php-client-2.0.0-RC7](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases)
2. In your script, require the autoloader from the vendor directory:

   ```
   require_once '/path/to/google-api-php-client-2.0.0-RC7/vendor/autoload.php`;
   ```

Comment: When including the autoload i am getting this error - Deprecated: google-api-php-client's autoloader was moved to src/Google/autoload.php in 1.1.3. This redirect will be removed in 1.2. Please adjust your code to use the new location.

Comment: That is because there is a legacy autoloader included with the package at "[src/Google/autoload.php](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/autoload.php)". You can use it, but you get the legacy warning. Instead, change your include path to use the autoloader at "vendor/autoload.php"